# How to grep the specific field value from json string using shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell

Below is my JSON string available in file, out of which I need to extract the value for `status` in shell script.

Expected Output: `status=success`

**response.json**

```
{"eventDate":null,"dateProccessed":null,"fileName":null,"status":"success"}
```

Please let me know, if you need any information

Answer (score 4):

Look into `jq`. It is a very handy json parser.

If you want to extract just the status you can do something like:

```
jq -r '.status' response.json

# output
success
```

You can format your output as well to follow the results you want.

```
jq -r '"status=\(.status)"' response.json

# output
status=success
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried that option, our unix flavor is not supporting the jq command. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You can try sed:

```
sed -n 's|.*"status":"\([^"]*\)".*|status=\1|p' response.json
```

Comment: How does this produce the expected output `status=success`?

Comment: @hek2mgl  \1 will capture `success`. It's not a brilliant solution, but it will work.

Comment: I was overlooking that the input json is a one line document. `sed` is not brilliant here but you are right, it will work in this case.